# jslt access parent field in for expression

Tags: json, jslt

**Hi, I want to use jslt to transform json , but happen an unsolvable problem.**

- 1. The input json data like this

```
{
    "user_id": "001",
    "friends": [{
        "friend_id": "002"
    }, {
        "friend_id": "003"
    }, {
        "friend_id": "004"
    }]
}
```

- 2. Then , what output json data I expected like the follow :

```
[{
    "user_id": "001",
    "friend_id": "002"
}, {
    "user_id": "001",
    "friend_id": "003"
}, {
    "user_id": "001",
    "friend_id": "004"
}]
```

- 3. In jslt expression , I use expression of for to traverse the array field friends :

```
[
    for (.friends) {
        "user_id": .user_id,
        "friend_id": .friend_id
    }
]
```

- 4. However , the treansform result can't get field user_id

```
[{
    "friend_id": "002"
}, {
    "friend_id": "003"
}, {
    "friend_id": "004"
}]
```

How can I access field user_id out of the scope related array field friends ?
Looking forward for your help， thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer is correct, but more complex than it needs to be. This is enough:

```
let user_id = (.user_id)
[ for (.friends) { "user_id": $user_id , "friend_id" : .friend_id } ]
```

Note that if you really want to report errors you could do it like this:

```
if (.user_id and .friends)
  let user_id = (.user_id)
  [ for (.friends) { "user_id": $user_id , "friend_id" : .friend_id } ]
else if (not(.user_id))
  error("user_id field missing")
else
  error("friends field missing")
```

Using `error` turns this into an exception at the Java level.

The reason the parent operator is not supported is that Jackson doesn't have a parent pointer in its nodes. That's a performance feature, because it means the node can be reused several places, saving CPU and memory.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a variable for the `user_id`, which you can then reference in the loop.

The following should fit your requirement:

```
if (.user_id)
  let user = .user_id
  if (.friends)
    [
      for (.friends) {
        "user_id": $user,
        "friend_id": .friend_id
      }
    ]
  else
    error("missing key 'friends'")
else
  error("missing key 'user_id'")
```

Comment: nice， thanks you ！ your answer fix my problem .